# Infinite time lapse using with cloud storge

Tags: backup, camera, cloud, google-photos

I was looking for a solution that would send my backup directly to cloud so that my phone memory would not fill up.
I am trying to make a very long time lapse (many frames over long period of time).

I was trying to use tasker to setup a loop job to take pictures and after some time (presumably after they are backed up to google photos) delete the file. Yet deleting the file resulted in photo being deleted from google photos too...

Any suggestions? Maybe I have not tried *all* Andorid time lapse apps or maybe some premium version of one has this kind of feature?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already Using Tasker, you can upload your photos to Dropbox (either set auto-upload in the Dropbox app or use the [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) plug-in). When a photo is uploaded to Dropbox, then deleted from the device, it remains in Dropbox.